# Como organizar data.frame por categorias de colunas?

Tags: r

Dado esse exemplo:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow  = 8))
colnames(data) <- LETTERS[1:5]

for (i in 1:8){data[i,] <- c(sample(LETTERS[1:5],3,FALSE),rep(NA,2))}
```

Como eu faço pra organizar este data.frame para que cada linha tenha seus elementos na coluna correspondente?

(Em outras palavras, todas os valores "A" na coluna "A", valores "B" na coluna "B" ... e valores ausentes como NA)

disso:
[image: disso...]

para isso:
[image: ...para isso.]

Answer (score 2):

Aqui vai uma solução em R base. Começa-se por criar uma matriz de índices de correspondências dos elementos da base aos números de cada coluna. Depois usa-se essa matriz para atribuir os valores a cada linha da base.

```
inx <- sapply(data, function(x) match(x, names(data)))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[i, ] <- NA
  j <- inx[i, ]
  j <- j[!is.na(j)]
  data[i, j] <- names(data)[j]
}

data
#     A    B    C    D    E
#1 <NA>    B    C <NA>    E
#2 <NA>    B    C    D <NA>
#3 <NA> <NA>    C    D    E
#4    A <NA>    C    D <NA>
#5 <NA>    B    C    D <NA>
#6    A <NA>    C    D <NA>
#7    A    B <NA>    D <NA>
#8    A    B    C <NA> <NA>
```

---

### Dados

Para os dados serem , reprodutíveis a base é criada com `set.seed` antes de serem gerados.

```
set.seed(2021)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow  = 8))
names(data) <- LETTERS[1:5]
for (i in 1:8){data[i,] <- c(sample(LETTERS[1:5],3,FALSE),rep(NA,2))}
```